Is this a V7sus2/V7 chord in bach?

When i was playing this prelude from bach i came across a new chord that i don't usually see in 18th century pieces
Also another question - in writing counterpoint in bach style it looks like two eight notes in a row can be dissonance without resolving is this true ? ( as i mentiond the interval between bass and alto with 2 and 7  )

See https://music.stackexchange.com/a/136428/78419 for one thing. It doesn't address all your issues here, but I'd say we don't need to recognize any chords with actual labels here besides ii and V.

Please replace the image with one showing clefs and key signatures.  Too much guesswork otherwise!

@nuggethead It says "E Major" on the image.

With some of Bach's music being written in open-score (Art of the Fugue, e.g.) format, and some other period music written using movable clefs, I think that simply stating "E major" is insufficient.  Yes, it's probably treble and bass clef, but how do we know?  Why not just give us an image that includes the clefs and key sigs?

I have changed the picture but as you can see it's still in e major and resolved to it

If you find that confusing, have a crack at the Loure from the fifth French suite.

Harmonically this is F♯m7, and the G♯ is a passing note. It is important to keep in mind that Bach did not really use Rameau style harmony theory, neither did he write Renaissance style counter point. The important thing here is that contrary to a suspension where the dissonance falls on a heavy beat and needs to be resolved the dissonance falls on a weak beat and does not resolve. This is not particularly uncommon, and there are quite a few cases of spicy harmonics going on in the work of Bach and other composers around that time.

Not a passing tone; an incomplete lower neighbor.

None. Now that i see it's just a double neighboour tone =/
